# Getting data from HTML table with input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that rows can be added for more items, I need to get the data from the input fields and store each row into a string, then push each string to an array.

I tried couple of loops with no success, I just get the first value of the table, I am very new to coding and still learning would greatly appreciate if someone can help me out, this is just a section of a form I am working on, I have linked the form to a data base and that is working, I need to store the table info as specified above to make the data simple to work with when getting the data from the database.

```js
function addRowEquipment() {
  let table = document.getElementById("equipment-table");
  let row = table.insertRow(2);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="New or Existing?"></td></tr>';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Equipment installed..."></td></tr>';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Serial Number..."></td></tr>';
  cell4.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Value per item..."></td></tr>';
}

function removeRowEquipment() {
  document.getElementById("equipment-table").deleteRow(2);
}

function getValue() {
  var tableData = document.getElementsByName("equipment")
  var tableValues = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
    if (tableData[i] != "") {
      tableValues.push(tableData[i].value);
    }
  }
  console.log(tableValues);
}
```

```css
.fieldset {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  margin: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 238, 238);
  ;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type=text],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  outline: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #2eaadc;
}

input[type=text]:hover {
  outline: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #2eaadc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Get Table Data</title>
</head>

<body>
  <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend class="legend">Equipment</legend>

    <label for="equipment" class="labels">Equipment:</label><br>
    <div><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRowEquipment()"><input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRowEquipment()"></div><br>
    <table id="equipment-table">
      <tr>
        <th>New/ Existing</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Serial Number</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="New or Existing?"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Equipment installed..."></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Serial Number..."></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Value per item..."></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="getValue()" />
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Need to add code for `insertCell()`

Comment: `I tried couple of loops with no success, I just get the first value of the table`. Please add what you tried to the question.

Comment: The question doesn't provide enough detail to suggest a solution.  Yes, you could store all the table values as an array of strings, but that's probably not the best way to send the data to the backend for storage in the database.  You probably want to give the inputs meaningful names and then upload the table as key-value FormData.

Comment: @Yogi I'm still trying to figure out if it is better so store the data on a data base or take the data from the form and convert it to a document then store it on a database. Either way I have to get the table data. Reason for pushing data from rows into strings is just a consistent way that the information goes to the document. I'm just struggling to get the values from the input fields.

Comment: @ksav this is where I am now, I can get the data from the input fields and store them into an array, but I want to store each row as a string in a array. I have updated my question with the function getValue().

Comment: @Ian do you still need help with this question?

Comment: @ksav no I'm all sorted thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I've added a class `my-row` to the table rows that will have inputs inside them. Then you can query them with `querySelectorAll`.

Then loop through the results of the query with `forEach`. Inside the loop, again use `querySelectorAll` to get the values from each the inputs inside the row.

Each of the values can be pushed into an array `rowValues`. Then `rowValues` can be pushed into `tableValues`.

```js
function addRowEquipment() {
  const table = document.getElementById("equipment-table");
  const row = table.insertRow(2);
  row.classList.add("my-row");
  const cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  const cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  const cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  const cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="New or Existing?"></td></tr>';
  cell2.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Equipment installed..."></td></tr>';
  cell3.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Serial Number..."></td></tr>';
  cell4.innerHTML = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Value per item..."></td></tr>';
}

function removeRowEquipment() {
  document.getElementById("equipment-table").deleteRow(2);
}

function getValue() {
  const tableData = document.getElementsByName("equipment")
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.my-row')
  const tableValues = new Array();

  rows.forEach(row => {
    const rowValues = new Array();
    const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input')
    inputs.forEach(input => {
      rowValues.push(input.value)
    })
    tableValues.push(rowValues)
  })

  console.log(tableValues);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fieldset">
  <legend class="legend">Equipment</legend>

  <label for="equipment" class="labels">Equipment:</label><br>
  <div><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRowEquipment()"><input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRowEquipment()"></div><br>
  <table id="equipment-table">
    <tr>
      <th>New/ Existing</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Serial Number</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="my-row">
      <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="New or Existing?"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Equipment installed..."></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Serial Number..."></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="equipment" placeholder="Value per item..."></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Get Value" onclick="getValue()" />
```